# Both the if and else Statement are being executed inside While Loop

Tags: java

Below is my code. Both the if and else statments are getting executed. Can someone help me out in this.

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String sql = "Select Attribute from attribute";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()) {
    if(Message.contains(rs.getString("Attribute")) || Subject.contains(rs.getString("Attribute")) == true) {
        response.sendRedirect("User_Send.jsp?auth=1");                              
    } else {
        Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
        String query = "insert into Message(Username,REmail,Subject,Message,Date,Status) values('"+ Username +"','" + To + "','" + Subject + "','" + Message + "','" + Date + "','" + "Done" + "')";
        int i = st2.executeUpdate(query);
        if(i!=0) {
            out.println("<h1 style='text-align:center;color:Red'>Message Sent Successfully</h1>");
        }                            
    }
}
```

Comment: Did You try debugging this issue?

Comment: Did you restart your eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Both the `if` and the `else` clauses will get executed if you have more than one result, and there are conditions in at least one result for each clause.

If you want more help, you need to tell us what is happening, not the result you think is happening.

Comment: I need to check if the text contains a string which is in database. if it contains the string then it will be redirected as shown above. if not the values should be inserted into the database. But the problem is both the if and else clauses are getting executed.

Comment: Just before your `if` statement do a `println()` to print out the value of `rs.getString()`. You will find that that `println()` executes more than once, and at least once it will satisfy the `if` condition and at least once it will not. While you're at it, print out the value of the attribute to which the code then compares the value.

Answer (score 0):

- Declare a boolean flag outside while.
- Set true in if
- After while check that flag
- If its true then redirect.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because in some iterations the if statement is true and other times it is false and goes to the else statement. It can't be both at the same time.

I highly recommend that you debug this, and if you don't know how to debug get started right now because you can't be a good programmer if you can't debug.